# wp8: programmatically created textblock is not displayed in app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Well,

I have created `textblock` programmatically in c#. but its not displayed in app. Whats wrong ?

Here's my updated c# code:

```
            double left = 0, top = 15, right = 0, bottom = 0;
            double left1 = 0, top1 = 12, right1 = 0, bottom1 = 12;
            TextBlock fileName = new TextBlock();
            fileName.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, right, bottom);
            fileName.FontSize = 30;
            fileName.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            fileName.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
            fileName.Text = "hello";
            StackPanel content = new StackPanel();
            content.Margin = new Thickness(left1, top1, right1, bottom1);
            content.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
            content.Children.Add(fileName);;
```

Comment: Just guessing, shouldn't you add it to datacontext?

Comment: ContentPanel.Children.Add or any other element, and add it to that

Comment: Can you update the question with your XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've added the `TextBlock` to the `StackPanel` but you haven't added the StackPanel to the visual tree. Assuming you want to add it to the `LayoutRoot`, you can do this

```
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(content);
```

As a side note, is there a reason you're doing this programmatically? Depending on your situation, you might be better off using a `UserControl`.

Comment: thank u. yes. there is an reason behind this. fileName.text will not be static. it will be changing by each file. so i have created this textblock programmatically.

Comment: Ah fair enough. Just making sure you're not creating extra work for yourself unnecessarily :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add it to a control something like `StackPanel`

```
StackPanel1.Children.Add(fileName);
```

Comment: even though its not displayed

Comment: you are adding `StackPanel` dynamically, so that also need to be added again to a existing control. That's why I ask for your XAML code